# How to target a virtual desktop with sendkey message in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi

Let's say I have installed http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc817881

I want to be able to sendmessage with win32 api but targeting the second virtual desktop while I will stay on first virtual desktop.

How to do that in c# ?

Update: for the context, what I'd like is to automate a manual task in background at periodic interval on an application which would reside in 2nd virtual desktop while I'm working on first desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provide describes a tool which is based on the Windows built-in desktop-mechanism.

Basically this means that you have really distinct desktops (with separate Logon!) which do not interact - they can't even see the windows of each other, i.e.unlike other "virtual desktop utilities" you can't move a window or application from one desktop to another.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687107%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) is the reference on MSDN to the use Desktop API which among other things explains the permissions issues etc. involved in such an undertaking.

Only way you could achieve what you want in this situation is to build a Windows Service which in turn monitors desktop startup/shutdown.

In case of desktop startup you need to start a process inside that desktop.
This process must offer some sort of desktop-agnostic IPC mechanism like TCP/IP or global mutex + global shared memory or similar...
You communicate with that process and this process does whatever you need (SendMessage, SendKeys...) inside that desktop on your behalf.

Comment: If this utility behaves like distinct desktop, why a macro made with this automation app http://bit.ly/x1WrIk doesn't work when the 2nd desktop is not active ?

Comment: @user310291 because it is on a different desktop with spearate login it solely depends on how the automation is implemented - there are other techniques than I described above to make it work but those are more in the area of "hacking" thus not recommended.

Comment: OK thanks, I don't think I'm going to be able to find a practical solution doable by me: I'm not a guru :)

Answer (score 3):

`SendKeys` and `SendMessage` are very different things. It's entirely unclear which one you're using.

You can't "target" anything with `SendKeys`. The only entity that can receive keyboard and mouse input in Windows is the window with the focus. Since something displayed on a virtual desktop will not have the focus, you can't do this.

You *can* however use the [`SendMessage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950.aspx) to send window messages to any window you wish. The `SendMessage` function accepts as its first parameter a handle to the window of interest (`HWND`). It doesn't matter if that window is focused, active, displayed, on a virtual desktop, or whatever.

Comment: IIRC `SendMessage` work "relative to the current desktop" (the desktop your thread is associated with)... in context of the "virtual desktop" the OP linked to this would only work IF you associate your thread with the "target desktop" (which is different from your own) for example via [`SetThreadDesktop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686250%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).